# What's wrong with my while loop condition code?

Tags: c++

I wrote the following code, but after I compiled it, and run it, nothing happens. I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

There are two "and conditions" in the `while` loop. When I take out 1 condition, it works fine, but when I put both conditions in, it no longer works.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n;
  cout << "Enter an integer greater than 10: ";
  cin >> n;

  int c=1;

  while ( (c*5 <= n*2) && (c*5 >= n) ) {
    cout << c*5 << endl;
    c = c+1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through it with a debugger? Also, this is an unnecessarily complicated condition and code. Why multiply three times c by 5? Don't repeat yourself.

Comment: I don't suppose you took a moment before posting this to put `cout << (c*5<=n*2) << ' ' << (c*5>=n) << '\n';` ***above*** the while-loop, just to see what you're about to start ?

Answer (score 6):

Your condition will never be true.  You start with `n > 10`, let's say `n == 11`.  Initially, `c == 1`.

Your condition is:

```
while ( (c*5 <= n*2) && (c*5 >= n) )
```

so that's:

```
while ( (1*5 <= 11*2) && (1*5 >= 11) )
```

or

```
while ( (5 <= 22) && (5 >= 11) )
```

5 is less than 11, so `5 >= 11` is false, and the loop never runs.

Answer (score 1):

If `n` is greater than `10`, then `c*5` (ie. `5`) will not be `>=n` so the loop condition will be `false` on the first evaluation.